# Как удалять все файлы в папке каждые 10 сек

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть папка "log" , ее путь "C:\log"
Где хранятся текстовые документы, и их нужно удалять каждые 10 секунд. Как это можно сделать? Спасибо.

Comment: Что конкретно? Удалить все файлы в папке или производить некую операцию каждые n секунд?

Comment: @Miron Удалить все Файлы в папке каждые n секунд

Comment: @Miron меня не устраивает использование php, очень важен именно питон, можно такое сделать на питоне? Я знаю можно с pyautogui но нужно делать отдельный файл и тп, я не знаю есть ли возможность сделать это в одну, две строчки кода на питоне поэтому и задал вопрос.

Comment: Я почему-то подумал про питон

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os, time
import shutil

os.chdir('C:\\log')
while True:
    for file in os.listdir():
        try:
            os.remove(file)
        except Exception: 
            shutil.rmtree(file)
    time.sleep(10)
```